# MYSQL Date Time Insert issue

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my sql line

**I tried:**

```
INSERT INTO delivery (Manifest_Id, , Expected_Start_DateTime, Expected_End_DateTime) VALUES ('SGP1361645SGP',2013-10-23 14:00:00,2013-10-23 18:00:00)
```

**and this**

```
INSERT INTO delivery (Manifest_Id, , Expected_Start_DateTime, Expected_End_DateTime) VALUES ('SGP1361645SGP','2013-10-23 14:00:00','2013-10-23 18:00:00')
```

Both return me

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' Expected_Start_DateTime, Expected_End_DateTime) VALUES ('SGP1361645SGP',2013-10' at line 1
```

My table structure is

```
delivery_id as int with auto increment ( not the issue )
Manifest_id as varchar
Expected_Start_DateTime as datetime
Expected_End_DateTime as datetime
```

ISSUE SOLVED.

**I got an extra comma in my line.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the comma

```
INSERT INTO delivery(Manifest_Id, Expected_Start_DateTime, Expected_End_DateTime)
VALUES ('SGP1361645SGP','2013-10-23 14:00:00','2013-10-23 18:00:00')
```

Comment: Oh sorry. din't realise i got a extra comma . thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra comma in your insert query remove that

Try this::

```
INSERT INTO delivery (Manifest_Id, Expected_Start_DateTime, Expected_End_DateTime) VALUES ('SGP1361645SGP',2013-10-23 14:00:00,2013-10-23 18:00:00)
```

Comment: Oh sorry. din't realise i got a extra comma . thanks